# php calculations and echoing?

Tags: php, function, operators

i have this function that takes two values and displays them, but its not doing the calculation right?

php code:

```
formatVote($votes_up,$votes_down)

$net_vote = $votes_up - $votes_down;

return <<<ENDOFRETURN
    <strong>$net_vote</strong>
ENDOFRETURN;
```

html page:

```
<?php
//rows retrieved from database....

formatVote($row['votes_up'],$row['votes_down']);
?>
```

p.s. i know the thier so no error from the mysql side of things,so the app is not calculating the results properly!

Comment: Well, what *is* it calculating? Example input and output, please!

Comment: 6-2 =0, when its meant to be display 2, sorry about that

Comment: Most likely, an logical error in a variable name somewhere. Without the real code hard to tell, suffice to say if PHP at any time stated 6-2=0 I'd bin it, but it hasn't so far.

Comment: Can you show an example of `var_dump($votes_up)` and `var_dump($votes_down)`?

Comment: true i have checked everything like 6 times everything is okay!!

Comment: its saying NULL for both

Comment: ...well, there's your problem, isn't it?

Comment: Also, note that the code you posted is nonsense and won't even compile. Just pointing this out in case this is your *real* code, or close to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to parse the variable like floatval($row['votes_up'])? You can also do the calculations straight from MySQL instead of creating such function.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/arithmetic-functions.html#operator_plus

Answer (score 0):

ok before we get an aswer i first need to you to do some testing for me and for yourself.
 in the code

```
formatVote($votes_up,$votes_down)

$net_vote = $votes_up - $votes_down;

return <<<ENDOFRETURN
    <strong>$net_vote</strong>
ENDOFRETURN;
```

please add

```
echo $votes_up + ' ' + $votes_down;
```

in the formatVote to find out what the values are.

This will be a changing post which will eventually be a correct answer as long as you keep up to date with me so we can solve this together

**PK**